# My bot glows green for a second, then stops

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, discord, discord.js

Right now, I only really want my bot to play one file directly off my computer. Here's the code:

```
const { Client, Intents, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');
const { joinVoiceChannel, createAudioPlayer, createAudioResource} = require('@discordjs/voice');
const { join } = require('path')
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES] });

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('messageCreate', msg => {
    if(msg.content === '!join') {
    connection = joinVoiceChannel({
        channelId: msg.member.voice.channel.id,
        guildId: msg.guild.id,
        adapterCreator: msg.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
    })
    }

    if (msg.content === '!play') {
    console.log(generateDependencyReport())
    const player = createAudioPlayer()
    let resource = createAudioResource(join('./Downloads/', 'musicFile.mp3'));
    player.play(resource)
    connection.subscribe(player)
    }
}
client.login(token);
```

I'm not really facing trouble getting my bot to join, but once I tell it to play the file, it doesn't play anything. Rather it flashes green for a second then just stays silent. I've made sure that all my intents are on, and I've also checked that all my dependencies are up to date. Thank you for reading! Btw discord.js v13 is the version I'm running

Comment: Any output in terminal after bot shuts down?

Comment: You forgot the `.subscribe(player);` function so that the bot actually does sound in the channel.

Comment: I was able to figure out what was wrong. For some reason the way I entered the file names wasn't working (I needed to include the direct path), thx for the help though guys!